# Testlink - Is it Possible to delete User Account

Tags: mysql, bitnami, testlink

I'm currently using test link 1.9.15.

Under User/Role i can only see disable option.
Is it possible to remove/Delete user account from Testlink?

If it is possible, can any one provide Query for same?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no provision for deleting user from GUI for now.You can add the functionality.
All the users are managed in `users` table. 
If you only want to delete inactive users.

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 0
```

Otherwise you can choose whatever field you want to delete from the table structure. 
[image]